# sed error in vagrant provision but ok in manual execute

Tags: sed, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I'm building a Vagrant project which will provision(am i use this word right?) a Minecraft server with a custom map. In the process of provision, I keep getting sed error `sed: -e expression #1, char 39: unknown option to 's'` but I didn't have the same error if I execute the sed commands manually. What wrong with my code?

Vagrantfile:

```
$map_install = <<INLINE_SCRIPT
cd /home/vagrant
cp /vagrant/min.config /home/vagrant/server.properties
sed -i 's/resource-pack=/resource-pack=https:\/\/example.com\/resources.zip/g' server.properties
INLINE_SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $map_install, privileged: false
end
```

server.properties:

```
#Minecraft server properties
resource-pack=
```

Comment: @Sundeep thx for the advise, i'm working on minimizing the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more research, I found that the `https://` protocol header somehow interference the original sed script even I escaped the forward slashes. So I change the sed delimiter from forward slashes to dollar signs which solve the problem. Now the sed command become:

```
sed -i 's$resource-pack=$resource-pack=https://example.com/resources.zip$g' server.properties
```